# Is it acceptable to flag one of your own posts notifying moderators of unreversed suspected serial voting?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, serial-voting

> The 3 downvotes yesterday in quick succession were not reversed. Were these legitimate downvotes? – bjb568 Aug 14 at 16:54   declined - We don't have any way of knowing.

I'd assume that it'd find its way to a developer since normal mods can't see individual votes, but it was just declined. Should I not flag one of my posts when I suspect serial voting? Should I use the "contact us" link instead?

> If the 24 hours has already passed and you don't feel like waiting in chat, you can then flag one of your posts and explain what happened so a moderator can look into it or post a new question on meta to get feedback and explanations.

<sup>from https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126857/237813</sup>

Comment: Yes, it's acceptable in general after waiting for at least 24 hours. Nevertheless, might be declined though :P ...

Comment: With just three downvotes, the general rule of thumb is to ignore them and go on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We have no way of knowing if those three votes were legitimate or not. We look at a lot more than just "a few votes cast around the same time" to determine if they're suspicious.  Two of the votes were on accepted answers and they were cast within 7 seconds of each other. That doesn't look good, but we can't say anything definitively from two votes. The third was cast over a minute later on a 0-score answer, so it could have easily been a legitimate vote from someone else. (One of the first two votes have since been cleared, so whatever scripts handle such things must have thought they were at least halfway sketchy.)

There's more recent voting activity than this on your account that does look suspicious, so I'll keep an eye on it to see if votes start accumulating from a particular user.

To answer your question though, three downvotes is not really much to go on, so it probably isn't worth flagging. We can't do anything. Now that it's up to nine votes it looks like something suspicious that does warrant a moderator looking at.

Comment: So how exactly how many votes is enough to be concerned about? 5?

Comment: @bjb568 If I tell you it's 5, then everyone can start downvoting each other exactly 4 times secure in the knowledge that they'll get away with it. The details of how suspicious votes are detected and dealt with are kept secret so people can't use that knowledge to stay just under the radar.

Comment: Oh, I meant the number to complain about, not the number to get it reversed. Or are they the same thing? :)

Comment: @bjb568 They're in the same ballpark.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I asked a [similar question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/282966/1090562) and flagged my answer. Also I flagged it almost a week ago and up till now it is still active (and I still receive a downvote each day).  Is there any other way to check what is going on?

Comment: @SalvadorDali There's not quite enough information yet to discern a pattern, but I'll keep an eye on it.

Comment: @BilltheLizard got it, thank you. I just thought that moderators can see whether the downvotes come from the same user of from different ones.

Answer (score 10):

I've said this before, but... 3 votes isn't suspicious. 3 votes is that tiny bit of Tabasco in your breakfast bloody mary that wakes you up and tells you it's morning. If you get three votes and think it's important, then you're not answering anywhere near enough questions - you've forgotten what Morning feels like.

Anyway.

I had a look at your votes. The three posts that got downvoted already had several downvotes. Maybe - just *maybe* - folks don't think they're particularly helpful. Food for thought. Celery for thought. All the chewin' none of the calories.  Bon appetit!