# Is there a way to deal with a persistent hater?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, serial-voting

It looks like in a last few weeks I really disappointed someone on SO. To such extent that I started to receive constant downvotes.

Yes, I have received downvotes previously, but they looked more naturally (mostly on recent questions/answers) with random intervals on time. Right now I am dealing with 1 downvote per day, on my questions with low views, which I have asked something like 4 months ago.

At the beginning I just ignored this, but after a few weeks, I started to think that I got a hater. Is there any reasonable way of dealing with this (beside just ignoring and hoping that everything will stabilize by itself)?

Comment: Flag for mod attention

Comment: @Bart I am not really sure what exactly should I flag? Should I flag my own question? If so I have to explain the underlying story, because if someone just downvoted my question this will most probably mean that the question was bad.

Comment: Yea just flag your question with a custom flag and explain why you think the downvotes should be reversed.

Comment: @SalvadorDali Just a note: I visited your profile because of your post (wanted to take a look at the questions), and not because of your avatar ;-) I didn't even notice it until I read your `About me` :-)

Comment: Yes, use an other flag and explain this story. Don't ask for reversal, ask for investigation. Or to escalate it to those who can have better acces.

Comment: Yey, I just got downvotes on 3 questions/answers not related to each other, other than they are all mine. I got a hater too! I wonder who I offended.

Comment: @Bart is there any other way to do this (I flagged my question almost a week ago and up till now it is still active and I still receive a downvote each day)?

Comment: Not really. Well you could contact the team using the contact link at the bottom. But just give it some time. More down votes are more evidence if something is really going on. And taking action might take some investigation mods can't do. Perhaps that caused the delay or maybe there's a crapton of flags to be handled again.